# How to stop referencing models in swift 4?

Tags: model-view-controller, model, swift4

When is goto edit data screen apply a model to fill data if user do make some changes but press back button the model saves the data? I am assigning the model to another demo model but it reflects the changed values.

Comment: <!-- language: lang-js -->var model = People() var temp = People() assigning temp = model </lang>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Override your model init method like below.

```
    required override init() {

    }

    required init(_ model: Person) {
    // Assign your Values  
    }
```

Use it Like

```
let obj  = People(model : Person)
```

to copy

Answer (score 0):

You can create copy method in reference class and assign it's property on back action.

Comment: Means i have to save that object somewhere before i copy that right?

Comment: No, you have to save reference before change property of reference.

Answer (score -1):

Either you can implement copyable protocol in your class model and assigning copy of that model.

or

Create struct instead of class.

Comment: Cannot not we make the model copyable?

Comment: override init() {
        
    }
    
    required init(_ model: MFTGiftBoard) {}